# django-'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I got this error, when redirecting to the result page. Is that because in the redirected page, the "POST.get" function cannot get what the user has entered in the form before redirecting?

**views.py**

```
class InputFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'inputform.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return ''.join(
        [
            reverse('result'),
            '?company=',self.request.POST.get('company'),
            '&region=',self.request.POST.get('region')  <is there anything wrong here---？       
        ]
        )


class ReulstView(FormView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    if form.is_valid():
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']

        self.queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)

        return render(request, 'result_list.html', {'form': form})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReulstView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))

        context["company"] = self.request.POST.get("company")
        context["region"] = self.request.POST.get("region")

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.all()
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  205.         form = self.get_form()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
  74.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /result_list/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Inputform**

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Company",error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the company name'},required=True)

    #region   This form can display correctly with drop down list
    iquery = Dupont.objects.values_list('region', flat=True).distinct()
    iquery_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(region,region)  for region in iquery]
    region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=iquery_choices)
```

For the same function, I tried another code, even though without error but cannot display the form data, it displays as none. Hope you can answer my question in the following link:

[django- why after redirecting, the form display "None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302186/django-why-after-redirecting-the-form-display-none)

Comment: Could you please provide more traceback or point which line of your code fails?

Comment: Hi @Paul, it doesn' point out which line is wrong..I have pased the whole traceback

Comment: Which text editor or IDE do you use?

Comment: Can you also post the code for `InputForm` ?

Comment: Looks like form_class() is None. Since it instantiates InputForm, it would be useful to take a look at the InputForm class source. Could you please provide it here?

Comment: Totally unrelated but it seems you're using a POST and a FormView for filtering a queryset. _This is wrong !_ the http POST method and FormViews are for submitting data (creating or updating something), search and filtering should be done with a GET request, and, in your case, a ListView.

Comment: hi,@bruno desthuilliers, indeed I need to submit the form first (that's why I use POST), and then based on the form entry, do some filtering thing and finally display the result and the submitted form data in a redirected page. Then in this case do you think if I could still use FormView? For example explanation, please see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302186/django-why-after-redirecting-the-form-display-none

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is your issue: You are using a `FormView` but haven't defined a form class to use. Either set a `form_class` attr on the class, or override the `get_form_class` method:

```
class ReulstView(FormView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result
    form_class = InputForm
```

Also, the `form_valid` method will receive the form instance, you don't need to instantiate it manually:

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    form = InputForm(self.request.POST)  # <- remove this line
    if form.is_valid():
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Arsh Singh, do you think there is thing wrong with "return render_to_response({"object_list":queryset})" in my views.py, as there reports an error after changing as you suggest?

Comment: @Elena am I right that now you getting another error?

Comment: @Elena I believe that your second question could be linked with the error you getting now. What exactly error you are getting now?

Comment: @Paul, It is "return outside function', therefore, I change the return render_to_response({"object_list":queryset}) to "return render(request, 'result_list.html', {'form': form})", error is the same...

Comment: Sorry @Arsh Singh, I misunderstood your answers, can please take a look at this question that I raised related to this example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302186/django-why-after-redirecting-the-form-display-none

Answer (score 2):

Lets make another thread. :)
The only way you can get "return outside function" error - you are trying to return something not from function. :) It could happen usually because of misstype or wrong indentation.
Could you please provide the code where you get this error? I believe that there is something wrong with indentation there.

```
class ReulstView(FormView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    if form.is_valid(): # <- it is not a function or method
                        #  it is a class declaration  
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']

        self.queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)

        return render(request, 'result_list.html', {'form': form})
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): #<- and this is a method
        #... all your following code
```

I'm not familiar with Django FormViews, but looks like correct code could be like this:

```
class ResultView(FormView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    model = Result

    def form_valid(self, form):
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']
        self.queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)    
        return render(request, 'result_list.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I have updated the views.py, I don't quite think it is because of indentation problem. The error occurs on the line of "return render(request, 'result_list.html', {'form': form})"

Comment: @Elena if the code from you question is right, you are trying to return not from function. But you are right - it is not identation problem. :) I updated my answer again.

Comment: I used to have code as you suggest, but @Arsh Singh's answer above suggests "removing the def form_valid(self, form) thing for FormView, so I removed that.

Comment: @Elena I didn't suggest to remove the `def form_valid...`, what I meant was that you don't need to instantiate the form manually, so just remove the `form = InputForm(...)` line from your `form_valid` function. I have edited my answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the problem is with your forms.py file. When you are importing and using the model in your forms.py file you are using parenthesis to define your model which you should not. For example if your model is lets suppose Post,
It should be defined as `Post` instead of `Post()`